# what is value of auto t1=std::make_tuple(case1==case2,integer)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, tuples

**DISCRIPTION

```
first, each player draws a single card from the deck
if one of the players drew a card of the winning suit and the other did not, then the player who drew a card of the winning suit wins the round
otherwise, the numbers written on the cards decide: if one player drew a card with a greater number on it than the other player, the player with the greater number wins, otherwise, if both players drew cards with the same numbers, the round ends in a draw
after the round is ended, the players return the cards they drew into the deck
```

**
*In the first line, there is a single character

denoting the winning suit.

In the second line, there is a single integer

denoting the number of rounds to be played.

Each of the next
lines denotes the cards that were drawn in a single round of the game and contains four space-separated values: , and denoting the suit of player's 1 card, the number on player's 1 card, the suit of player's 2 card, and the number of player's 2 card respectively. *

```
input:-
B
5
A 2 B 1
A 7 D 2
B 5 D 13
B 3 B 1
A 12 C 12
```

```
int main() {
    char winning_suit;
    std::cin >> winning_suit;
    unsigned tests;
    std::cin >> tests;
    while (tests--) {
        char suit1, suit2;
        int number1, number2;
        std::cin >> suit1 >> number1 >> suit2 >> number2;

        auto t1 = std::make_tuple(suit1 == winning_suit, number1);
        auto t2 = std::make_tuple(suit2 == winning_suit, number2);

        if (t1 > t2) {
            std::cout << "Player 1 wins\n";
        } else if (t1 < t2) {
            std::cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Draw\n";
        }
    }
}
```

```
output:-
Player 2 wins
Player 1 wins
Player 1 wins
Player 1 wins
Draw
```

Comment: "auto t1=std::make_tuple(case1==case2,integer)". So t1 will be a tupple with two values, the first is boolean with the result of "case1==case2" comparison and the second an integer provided by number1 and number2 in your code.
I don't understand what is your question

Answer (score 0):

The statements

```
auto t1 = std::make_tuple(suit1 == winning_suit, number1);
auto t2 = std::make_tuple(suit2 == winning_suit, number2);
```

both declare and initialise a `std::tuple<bool, int>`.

The first time round the loop, they have the values

```
{ false, 2 }
{ true, 1 }
```

They are then compared, using [`std::tuple::operator>` and `std::tuple::operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp), which orders them based on the first element, then by the second element. This is a [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), specifically

> an order on a Cartesian product of partially ordered sets

Here that means all cards in the winning suit are greater than all cards in other suits, and when suit is tied, higher numbered cards are greater than lower numbered cards.